# Extract HTML from jsonp's key/ VALUE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

Here is my code I'm trying to process data from the jsonp.html: `<a><img/><div></div></a>` and I want to take that value and target the img tag or a tag.

```
var URL = 'http://radleaf.com/w/1.0/arj?o=713142125&auid=258624&c.env=rvw';
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data,status) {
        var ad = data['ads']['ad'][0];
        $.each(ad, function(key, val) {
            $('#rotator').append('<h2 id="' + key + '">'+key+':' + val + '</h2>');
            if(key=='html'){
                  //NEED HELP HERE VALUE HAS MULT TAG HOW DO I ACCESS THOSE TAGS?             
               }
        });
        console.log(data);
    },
    jsonpCallback: 'foobar'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (key=='html') {
     var $html = $(val);
     var $img = $html.find('img'); // get the img tag

     alert($img.prop('src')); // just to test
}
```

Comment: Rory your awesome bro thanks for the help. It really means a lot when you can post and get a quick reply. And it worked for me, my mistake was not enclosing my val in $(). Once again thanks bro...

Comment: Rory need to bother you again. I've been working all day to try to test whether that $img object on a .error() function but it's not working. The data in the JSONP request I want to test if that img src fails or test if that image src fails. To create a failsafe and populate new content in my Div.

Comment: So in short can I test the url of the jsonp data that I returned?

Comment: I think you can but I'm not 100% sure. You're probably best to ask that in a new question. Don't forget to accept this one first though :)

Answer (score -1):

You should add ID to the tags you want to get values from and use Jquery to get the values with `$("#idofthetag").html()` or `$("idofthetag").val()` if is an

Comment: 2 of the methods you have shown as jQuery methods do not exist in the API

Comment: Pau I don't think it's fair that you give me a thumbs down cause I'm using JSONP and I'm getting the JSONP value and testing if the url loads correctly to ensure there are no errors on that page.

Comment: my reputation is 29, I can't give thumbs down until it is 125.